# Can I delay a refresh of a page using lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component, activated with a quick action that updates an object (lead) status. Then it refreshes the record page.

The issue I am having is that the refresh does NOT show the new status, but the previous one, if I wait a couple of seconds, and manually refreshes the page again, the change is displayed.

1. is there a way to 'Delay' the refresh of the page by a certain time?
2. Maybe a different approach?

Here is my code:

**LeadSendToConvert.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="LeadSendToConvert_LC" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    Updating lead status to Convert by Partner ... </aura:component>
```

**LeadSendToConvertController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.updateLeadStatus(component, event, helper);
    }
})
```

**LeadSendToConvertHelper.js**

```
({
    updateLeadStatus : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.updateLeadStatusSendToConvert");
        var leadId = component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({
            leadRecordId : leadId
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {    
            var state = response.getState();

            if(state == "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()) {
                var leadRecordId = response.getReturnValue();
                helper.openRecord(leadId);
            }
            else
                helper.openRecord(leadId);
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    openRecord : function(leadRecordId) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        if(urlEvent) {
            urlEvent.setParams({
                "url": "/" + leadRecordId
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
        } else {
            alert('Outside of lightning scope.');
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
        }, 500);
    } 
})
```

**LeadSendToConvert_LC.cls**

```
public class LeadSendToConvert_LC {
    @AuraEnabled

    public static String updateLeadStatusSendToConvert(String leadRecordId) {
        String updateLeadId = null;
        try {
            lead iLead = new lead();
            iLead.id = leadRecordId;
            iLead.Status = 'Partner Only - Waiting to Convert';
            update iLead;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Cannot update lead status: ' + updateLeadId + ' ::: error: ' +  e.getMessage());
        }

        return updateLeadId;
    }
}
```

Answer to @pranay - Currently there are no future/queuable actions in Lead Trigger.

I removed the Else (also tweaked code a bit) - Same result. field is updated in the background, but when record page is refreshed, the change is not displaeyd. only after a second manual refresh.

Comment: is there any future / queuable method in lead trigger?

Comment: Also can you remove the else part in updateLeadStatus method and see if it works?

Comment: I don't see any issues in the provided code. Even you don't need a separate `openRecord` method to refresh the page. You can fire both 'e.force:closeQuickAction' & 'e.force:refreshView' from the callback method.

Comment: Thanks @SarojBera - I also didn't see issues in code, but using your method, fixed the issue. please add as answer so I can accept.

Comment: What I can tell from my personal experience with these kind of issues is Using 

    window.location.href =  '/'+recordid ;

will help you a lot. I know this is not the best practice but till the salesforce comes up with something, You can use it.

Comment: @Saariko I know there's a way to cause the page to refresh once the DML has completed in Lightning. I don't recall what it is at the moment, but will post it once I recall or find the link with the info that was shared with me a few months ago.

Comment: @Saariko - I have posted my solution as an answer to your Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate `openRecord` method to refresh the page. You can fire both 'e.force:closeQuickAction' & 'e.force:refreshView' from the callback method to get the refreshed view of the updated record.

---

Added by @saariko

Thank you, here is my solution with your suggestion:

```
({
    updateLeadStatus : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.updateLeadStatusSendToConvert");
        var leadId = component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({
            leadRecordId : leadId
        });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {    
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state == "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()) {

                $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
                $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be a couple of reasons why the update isn't showing up...

1. To call a helper method from the `ComponentNameHelper.js` file you use `this.functionName()` instead of `helper.functionName()` (which is for calling helper functions from `ComponentNameController.js`). `helper.openRecord(leadId);` is not being called and is failing silently (as with a lot of salesforce lightning errors).
2. When you use setTimeout you would need to use `$A.getCallback`, since you are...

   > Modifying Components Outside the Framework Lifecycle

   Please see [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm) for further info.

As you mentioned @Saroj Bera's solution should work fine, since a delay is not why it wasn't working.